# JTRevealSidebar: The Sidebar is sometimes white

Tags: ios, sidebar

i use the JTRevealSidebarV2 and have a problem. The sidebar is not always visible. It is sometimes white. Have anybody a solution?

This is the Code for see and dismiss the sidebar:

`// This is an examle to configure your sidebar view through a custom UIViewController
- (UIView *)viewForLeftSidebar {
    [self changeAllButtonImageUnpressed];`

```
// Use applicationViewFrame to get the correctly calculated view's frame
// for use as a reference to our sidebar's view
CGRect viewFrame = self.navigationController.applicationViewFrame;
UITableViewController *controller = self.leftSidebarViewController;    NSLog(@"Controller.view %@", controller.view);
if ( controller == nil ) {
    self.leftSidebarViewController = [[SidebarViewController alloc] init];
    self.leftSidebarViewController.sidebarDelegate = self;
    controller = self.leftSidebarViewController;
    //controller.title = @"LeftSidebarViewController";
}

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, viewFrame.origin.y, 250, viewFrame.size.height);
controller.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

return controller.view;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you open a sidebar than hit the home key. reopen the app and its all messed up